# How do I get the return value I want from my stored procedure?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a stored procedure and return the `@KeyNo` rather than the return value. I've attached an image of the stored procedure I am using.

I execute the stored procedure as follows:

```
for(int row = start.Row; row <= end.Row; row++)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetKeyNumber", homelinkconn);
    cmd.CommandType= CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KeyName", "VGMNO");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KeyNo", SqlDbType.Int);

    var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyNo", SqlDbType.Int);
    returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    var key = returnParameter.Value;
    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count-1]["VGMNO"] = key;
}
```

However, after calling this, it's returning 0, rather than 172155. Any advice on how to fix this?

Stored procedure:

[image]

Comment: You don't SELECT a return value, you RETURN it. And I'm surprised that works at all since you add the same parameter twice, is that really exactly your code?

Comment: I've updated my code, and am now getting the return value that I wanted. However, it will only work for one line, and if the excel file I attempt to import has any more, I get an error saying "Column 'VGMNo' does not allow DBNull.Value" I'm assuming my logic for my loop isn't correct.

Comment: There are so many problems with this code it is difficult to know what your goal is. Are you trying to set the `VGMNO` column value in a data table for every row to the same `KeyNo` value?

Comment: I am trying to have each row in the VGMNO column have a unique KeyNo value

Comment: So, `[GetKeyNumber]` will return different values on each call even with the same input?

Comment: Correct, the @KeyNo that is being returned is always incremented by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments I think you are confusing a lot of concepts. It looks like you want `OUTPUT`, not `RETURN` values.

I'm still unclear what you want to do to your data table, but this is how you can get a new key for every "row":

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetKeyNumber", homelinkconn))
{
    //setup the command one time, not in every loop iteration
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KeyName", "VGMNO");

    SqlParameter par_KeyNo = new SqlParameter("@KeyNo", SqlDbType.Int);
    par_KeyNo.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(par_KeyNo);

    for (int row = start.Row; row <= end.Row; row++)
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        var key = par_KeyNo.Value;

        //unlcear what you want to do here. Currently you would be 
        //resetting the last row over and over every iteration
        dt.Rows[????]["VGMNO"] = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Crowcoder, thank you so much for writing that. However, I am still not able to use this if my excel file has more than one line of data in it.

Comment: That's where your question is missing context, we don't know what `start` and `end` are or how they are obtained. And we don't know how the excel file and the data table tie together. So that is a different problem, I think.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's most likely an issue with how I define start and end. `var excel = new ExcelPackage(Upload.FileContent); var dt = excel.ToDataTable(); ExcelWorksheet workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets[1]; var start = workSheet.Dimension.Start; var end = workSheet.Dimension.End;`

Comment: I can attach an image if that would be more helpful.

Comment: It may help if you add that code to the question. In the debugger you should be able to see the values of `start.row` and `end.row`, are they what you expect?

Comment: The values are exactly as they should be. The only thing I can think of now that might be the issue is when I assign each cell to the value "key." `dt.Rows[row]["VGMNO"] = key;` doesn't work either

Comment: Updating the data table won't update the spreadsheet - it becomes disconnected data at that point. I'm not sure which Excel library you are using but you may want to update the sheet directly instead of dumping it to a data table.

Comment: I am using the EPPlus library. However, I'm not sure updating the sheet directly is necessarily the right fix, because as it stands I can import excel files, but only if they have one line of data.

Comment: Finally got the issue solved. The problem existed somewhere in my for loop. For anyone wondering, this did the trick: `for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) { cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); var key = par_KeyNo.Value; dt.Rows[i]["VGMNO"] = key; }`

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to return a value, you should use ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery.

There is an example here:
[ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Return values have nothing to do with how you execute the command as long as you execute it.

Comment: And that would be specified in the stored proc, which OP has not posted. Either way, the code above should be using ExecuteScalar...

Comment: Actually, if just the return value is desired it should be `ExecuteNonQuery`. The parameter with direction `ReturnValue` will be populated and available after executing the command.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SqlDataReader lSqlDataReader = lSqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (lSqlDataReader.Read())
      Here you get all return values in lSqlDataReader
```

UPDATE
Edit your procedur as

```
select @KeyNo as 'KeyNo', @return_value as 'Return Value';
```

and 
in C# code write

```
var ReturnValue=0;
var KeyNo=0;
while (lSqlDataReader.Read())
  {
   ReturnValue=lSqlDataReader.GetInt("Return Value");
   KeyNo=lSqlDataReader.GetInt("KeyNo");
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

ExecuteNonQuery() returns the number of rows affected 
ExecuteScalar() returns the first column of first row

Comment: Return values have nothing to do with how you execute the command as long as you execute it.